# Back-up a site collection that contain overlay calendars will keeping referencing the old calendars URL

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, deployment, backup

I have a community site collection, which contain 5 calendars Apps, and I have overlayed 4 calendars together inside a general  calendar.

Then I have backup the site collection from my development environment which contain the 5 calendars, and then I restore it to the new UAT server. I have noted that the five calendars were restored successfully, but when I click on the general calendar I have noted that the overlay calendars no more exists , and when I click on certain calendar inside the “Calender in view”    I have noted that it contains the old URL and not the new URL . while the 5 calendar themselves  were successfully restored to the new URL for the site collection, but the overlyed calender info still refer to the development environemtn URL.

Second problem is that I have added some Prompted links and I specify the background imag URL , then when I restore the site collection in the UAT that back ground images still refer to the old development URL?
Any help on the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the calendars, this is an annoying bug. SharePoint appears to store the absolute URLs to the calendars. I've come across the same issue when setting up calendars on the site using the internal URL, and then the external users can't use them. Very annoying. Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution other than reconfigure them manually. Might be possible with a PowerShell script.

I haven't worked with promoted links that much yet, but I would imagine the same applies. However, you should be able to use a relative URL to your image, instead of the absolute.

HTH